# how to move several panels on to different locations on a button click event in winform using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have generated several panels on an event and in those panel i have a button which will delete that particular panel. now i want to shift the other panels when i am deleting a panel that there's no gap remain. my panel generation function is ....

```
public void generate_editpanel(string c)
    {
        int i, j, k, b;
        int m, n;


        //Bitmap bmp = drawled(16, 16, Color.Black, Color.White);
        //imglst.Images.Add(bmp);


        for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            epnl[i] = new Panel();
            epnl[i].Visible = false;
            epnl[i].Enabled = true;
            epnl[i].Name = "epnl" + c;
            epnl[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, 0);
            epnl[i].Width = 260;
            epnl[i].Height = 173;
            epnl[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            EditPanel.Controls.Add(epnl[i]);


            grid[i] = new DataGridView();
            cellstl = new DataGridViewCellStyle();

            grid[i].Visible = true;
            grid[i].AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            grid[i].AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            grid[i].AllowUserToOrderColumns = false;
            grid[i].AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            grid[i].AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
            grid[i].ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
            grid[i].RowHeadersVisible = false;
            grid[i].Name = "grid" + c;
            grid[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120,5);
            grid[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(129, 129);
            grid[i].BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
            grid[i].GridColor = Color.Green;
            grid[i].CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
            grid[i].ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
            fill(Color.Black, Color.White);
            for (j = 1; j <= 8; j++)
            {

                col = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
                col.Width = 16;
                col.Image = imglst.Images[0];
                col.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal;
                grid[i].Columns.Add(col);
                grid[i].Columns[j - 1].FillWeight = 1;
            }
            for (k = 1; k <= 8; k++)
            {
                grid[i].Rows.Add();
                grid[i].Rows[k - 1].Height = 16;
            }
            cellstl.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            cellstl.BackColor = Color.White;
            grid[i].CellMouseClick += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(this.gridmouseclick);
            grid[i].CellMouseMove += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(this.gridmousemove);
            grid[i].CellMouseDown += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(this.gridmousedown);
            grid[i].CellMouseUp += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(this.gridmouseup);

            //for (m = 1; m <= 8; m++)
            //{
            //    for (n = 1; n <= 8; n++)
            //    {
            //        griddata[m, n] = 0;
            //    }
            //}
            epnl[i].Controls.Add(grid[i]);




            cbtn[i] = new Button();
            cbtn[i].Visible = true;
            cbtn[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 1);
            cbtn[i].Name = "ctbn" + c;
            cbtn[i].Width = 25;
            cbtn[i].Height = 25;
            cbtn[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.dropedit);
            cbtn[i].BackgroundImage = Video_Project.Properties.Resources.w2;
            cbtn[i].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            epnl[i].Controls.Add(cbtn[i]);


            lbl[i] = new Label();
            lbl[i].Visible = true;
            lbl[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 79);
            lbl[i].Name = "lblr" + c;
            lbl[i].Width = 45;
            lbl[i].Height = 13;
            lbl[i].Text = "Repeat:";
            epnl[i].Controls.Add(lbl[i]);


            lbl[i] = new Label();
            lbl[i].Visible = true;
            lbl[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 106);
            lbl[i].Name = "lbls" + c;
            lbl[i].Width = 45;
            lbl[i].Height = 13;
            lbl[i].Text = "Speed:";
            epnl[i].Controls.Add(lbl[i]);


            lbl[i] = new Label();
            lbl[i].Visible = true;
            lbl[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 145);
            lbl[i].Name = "lblt" + c;
            lbl[i].Width = 45;
            lbl[i].Height = 13;
            lbl[i].Text = "Text:";
            epnl[i].Controls.Add(lbl[i]);


            lbl[i] = new Label();
            lbl[i].Visible = true;
            lbl[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0);
            lbl[i].AutoSize = false;
            lbl[i].Width = 70;
            lbl[i].Height = 70;
            lbl[i].Text = c;
            lbl[i].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            epnl[i].Controls.Add(lbl[i]);
            b = Convert.ToInt32(c);
            b += 1;
            c = Convert.ToString(b);

            txt[i] = new TextBox();
            txt[i].Visible = true;
            txt[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 72);
            txt[i].Name = "txtr" + c;
            txt[i].Width = 35;
            txt[i].Height = 20;
            txt[i].MaxLength = 2;
            epnl[i].Controls.Add(txt[i]);


            txt[i] = new TextBox();
            txt[i].Visible = true;
            txt[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 103);
            txt[i].Name = "txts" + c;
            txt[i].Width = 35;
            txt[i].Height = 20;
            txt[i].MaxLength = 2;
            epnl[i].Controls.Add(txt[i]);


            txt[i] = new TextBox();
            txt[i].Visible = true;
            txt[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 142);
            txt[i].Name = "txtt" + c;
            txt[i].Width = 200;
            txt[i].Height = 20;
            txt[i].MaxLength = 250;
            epnl[i].Controls.Add(txt[i]);

            x = x + 280;
        }

    }
```

i am setting the visible mode of a particular panel on another event

```
 private void viewscreen_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                //string c = Convert.ToString(b);
                //generate_editpanel(c);
                if (b == i)
                {
                    epnl[i].Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and i am deleting a particular panel on another event ...

```
public void dropedit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            if (cbtn[i].Capture)
            {
                EditPanel.Controls.Remove(epnl[i]);
                epnl[i].Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

so now i am getting a gap when i am deleting a panel i want to shift the rest of the panels to left and remove that gap. any one pls help ... if u need some other info pls let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y62k236c.aspx)  as a container for panels.

Comment: ok so you are saying that i should add those panels in a flowlayoutpanel? will that solve the location problem? i mean dont i have to use any location to re-shuffle them? i never used flowlayoutpanel before